# Joining 2 tables using sqlite commands

Tags: sqlite, join

I have created a database named sample.db.

I have imported 2 csv files -test and test1(tables in the database)

I want to join the two tables based on 3 columns - timestamp,longitude and latitude.

test

```
o3,pm,co,so2,no2,longitude,latitude,timestamp     
61,82,52,49,54,10.2466,56.2091,1410693900    
66,83,51,44,51,10.2466,56.2091,1410694200    
68,80,54,41,56,10.2466,56.2091,1410694500    
66,79,53,42,59,10.2466,56.2091,1410694800    
71,75,57,45,61,10.2466,56.2091,1410695100    
75,75,60,50,61,10.2466,56.2091,1410695400   
122,97,172,40,53,10.2507,56.2026,1412101200
```

test1

```
status,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,extID,medianMeasuredTime,TIMESTAMP,vehicleCount,_id,REPORT_ID,Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh    
OK,61,60,668,61,1410693900,4,20746723,158324,56.2091,10.2466,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,61,60,668,61,1410694200,1,20747172,158324,56.2091,10.2466,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,63,58,668,63,1410694500,3,20747545,158324,56.2091,10.2466,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,71,52,668,71,1410694800,6,20747994,158324,56.2091,10.2466,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,67,55,668,67,1410695100,5,20748443,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2091,10.2466,1030,52,71
OK,62,59,668,62,1410695400,6,20748892,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2091,10.2466,1030,52,71
OK,67,55,668,67,1412101200,13,20749341,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2026,10.2507,1030,52,71
```

Expected output

```
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,medianMeasuredTime,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
61,82,52,49,54,10.2466,56.2091,1410693900,61,60,61,1030,52,71
66,83,51,44,51,10.2466,56.2091,1410694200,61,60,61,1030,52,71
68,80,54,41,56,10.2466,56.2091,1410694500,63,58,63,1030,52,71
66,79,53,42,59,10.2466,56.2091,1410694800,71,52,71,1030,52,71
71,75,57,45,61,10.2466,56.2091,1410695100,67,55,67,1030,52,71
75,75,60,50,61,10.2466,56.2091,1410695400,62,59,62,1030,52,71
122,97,172,40,53,10.2507,56.2026,1412101200,67,55,67,1030,52,71
```

As you can see, I want to join based on timestamp,longitude and latitude. There are two longitude values in table2(test1). So i want to compare the longitude in table1 matched any of the longitude values in table2. Similarly latitude.

What i have tried

```
select * 
from test 
join test1 
    on test.timestamp=test1.TIMESTAMP and
    test.longitude=test1.Long1 or 
    test.longitude=test1.Long2 and 
    test.latitude=test1.Lat1 or 
    test.latitude=test1.Lat2;
```

Also I want to store the result in a new table.

I am new to sqlite. So please help :)

Comment: Please tag correctly. What have you tried? I don't see a SQL statement showing what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: select * from test join test1 on (test.latitude=test1.latitude and test.longitude=test1.longitude and test.timestamp=test1.timestamp )

Comment: Please don't put answers in comments. Especially when they aren't correct.

Comment: @SloanThrasher sir i have mentioned what i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis to group your conditions. You want rows where the timestamp matches AND (either lat/long pair 1 matches OR lat/long pair2 matches)

```
select * 
from test 
join test1 
    on test.timestamp = test1.TIMESTAMP and
    ((test.longitude = test1.Long1 and test.latitude = test1.Lat1) or
     (test.longitude = test1.Long2 and test.latitude = test1.Lat2));
```

Comment: This works perfect sir ! Can you tell me how to store the result in a new table?

Comment: Lookup the INSERT from SELECT syntax. Basically, create a SELECT statement that returns the columns in the target table, and use that as the data source for an INSERT statement.

Answer (score -1):

SQL command for `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT latitude
FROM test
INNER JOIN test1 ON test.latitude = test1.latitude;
```

Repeat for other columns.